# Increasing number in jquery as row is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

May the question will be difficult for explaining and understanding too.

I have a `table` which has some `rows` and `button` of **add row**.

Table `rows` contain `input` field, having specific `name`.

For eg.: I have two rows, the first row has `name="qty1"` then the second `row` is having `name="qty2"`. And for adding the third row, there is button `add row`.

So, now the third `row` will be added.

The `name` of `input` in the third row should be `name="qty3"`, but it is only `name="qty"`.

I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var markup = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="item" value="" placeholder="Item"></td><td><select class="country" name="what"><option value="Select Part">Select Part</option><option value="1">Part 1</option><option value="2">Part 2</option><option value="3">Part 3</option><option value="4">Part 4</option><option value="5">Part 5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td></tr>';
            $("table").append(markup);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
     
 <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="text" name="customer" value="" placeholder="Customer Name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
 <th>Service</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    
  </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="item1" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
   <td><select class="country" name="what1">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="item2" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
   <td><select class="country" name="what2">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty2" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
    </tr>
 
 <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Save
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
```

**So, my question is how to increase the numbers as per rows?**

Comment: count your table rows and then add that number to the class in `markup` you're appending.

Comment: @DawidZbiński How to do that? Can you please edit my codes for the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter as name and increment it in each click:
**Update:** Use `insertBefore()` method to add the rows before the submit button.
I reccomend you take a look on [DOM insertion outside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/) and [DOM insertion inside](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) methods.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cont = 3
    $(".add-row").click(function() {
        var markup = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="item" value="" placeholder="Item"></td><td><select class="country" name="what"><option value="Select Part">Select Part</option><option value="1">Part 1</option><option value="2">Part 2</option><option value="3">Part 3</option><option value="4">Part 4</option><option value="5">Part 5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="qty' + cont + '" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td></tr>';
        $(markup).insertBefore($('button[type="submit"]').closest("tr"));
        cont++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">

    <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" name="customer" value="" placeholder="Customer Name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Qty</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="item1" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
            <td><select class="country" name="what1">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="item2" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
            <td><select class="country" name="what2">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty2" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Save
        </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, One more question, Why the new rows are added after `submit` button & not before?

Comment: Because $("table").append() add new elements after last element to table,  in this case last <tr></tr> wich there is after submit button

Comment: So, how Can I change that?

Comment: Should I add `id` to the last `<tr>`?

Comment: Sure, where you need add the new elements? I will update my answer

Comment: Just after the second row.. in continuous.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Count children of table tbody with .children().length() to get the next number**

```
var nextNumber = $("#chiru_inv tbody").children().length - 2;
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h93xmecm/)

---

You can also consider learning technologies that are superior to jquery in these kinds of tasks, such as React.js, Angular, Vue.js

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1 vote if I can), One more question, Why the new rows are added after `submit` button & not before?

Comment: @BTC The jquery .append() function inserts new HTML at the end of the specified element. To insert the row before the last row, **assign an id to the last row and use this function**: [jQuery Documentation: .insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, get the number of inputs that already exist. Then when you add new input, always increase that number and add it to the input's name `qty + the number of existing inputs`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elCount = $("form table input[name^='qty']").length;
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        elCount++;
        var markup = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="item" value="" placeholder="Item"></td><td><select class="country" name="what"><option value="Select Part">Select Part</option><option value="1">Part 1</option><option value="2">Part 2</option><option value="3">Part 3</option><option value="4">Part 4</option><option value="5">Part 5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="qty' + elCount + '" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td></tr>';
        $("table").append(markup);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1 vote if I can), One more question, Why the new rows are added after `submit` button & not before?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a specified CSS `class` for input row and using that following could be one of the solution:

```
// Get all rows
// Note: expecting input row having class 'inputRow'
var allRows = $('table tr.inputRow');

// Set proper value to 'name' attribute
allRows.last().find('input[name=item]').attr('name', 'item' + allRows.length);
```

HTML `table` tag also requires a fix:

```
<table>

  <tbody>
    <!-- data rows goes here -->
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <!-- save button row goes here-->
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    var markup = '<tr class="inputRow"><td><input type="text" name="item" value="" placeholder="Item"></td><td><select class="country" name="what"><option value="Select Part">Select Part</option><option value="1">Part 1</option><option value="2">Part 2</option><option value="3">Part 3</option><option value="4">Part 4</option><option value="5">Part 5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td></tr>';
    $("table > tbody").append(markup);

    // Get all rows
    // Note: expecting input row having class 'inputRow'
    var allRows = $('table tr.inputRow');

    // Set proper value to 'name' attribute
    allRows.last().find('input[name=item]').attr('name', 'item' + allRows.length);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">

  <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input type="text" name="customer" value="" placeholder="Customer Name">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Qty</th>

      </tr>

      <tr class="inputRow">
        <td><input type="text" name="item1" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
        <td><select class="country" name="what1">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inputRow">
        <td><input type="text" name="item2" value="" placeholder="Item"></td>
        <td><select class="country" name="what2">
  <option value="Select Part">Select Part</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
  <option value="4">Part 4</option>
  <option value="5">Part 5</option>
</select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty2" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Save
        </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1 vote if I can), One more question, Why the new rows are added after `submit` button & not before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I would suggest you flag your rows in the table by adding a class in your markup (in my example qtyRow):

```
var markup = '<tr class="qtyRow"><td><input type="text" name="item" 
value="" placeholder="Item"></td><td><select class="country" 
name="what"><option value="Select Part">Select Part</option><option 
value="1">Part 1</option><option value="2">Part 2</option><option 
value="3">Part 3</option><option value="4">Part 4</option><option 
value="5">Part 5</option></select></td><td><input type="text" 
name="qty" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></td></tr>';
```

In your example there are two rows by default. These should also have the qtyRow class.
You can get the amoutn of rows by this and add 1 for the new qtyRow:

```
var number = $("tr.qtyRow").length + 1;
```

Now you need to change name="qty" to name="qtyn" where is the new number from the codeline above. Inside your $(".add-row").click() listener you need to add after the declaration of markup:

```
var number = $("tr.qtyRow").length + 1;
markup = markup.peplace('name="qty"', 'name="qty' + number + '"');
```

Please let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't tried as I went for https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178244/8905387